# Limit of the integral of Gaussian kernel over part of Matern Covariance function

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, bessel-functions

I am trying to compute the following integral during my research, I have some intuitive belief that this limit will goes to 0 as x increases. However, I failed to prove it, any one has some ideas?

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x} \exp(-0.5 x w^2)}{w^{p} K_p(w)} d w = 0$$

Notice here:

$K_p$ is the modified Bessel function with $p \in (0, 0.5)$. $w^p K_p(w)$ is part of Matern covariance function.

$\int_0^\infty \sqrt{x} \exp(-0.5 x w^2) d w $ is some constant does not depend on $x$ (Gaussian density).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is not zero. Assume that $p$, with $\operatorname{Re}(p)>0$, is fixed. First we note that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{w \to 0^ +  } w^p K_p (w) = 2^{p - 1} \Gamma (p),
$$
and
$$
K_p (w) \sim \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2w}}} {\rm e}^{ - w} ,\quad w \to  + \infty  
$$
(see, for instance, [$\S10.30$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.30) of the DLMF). Now consider
$$
\sqrt x \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - \frac{1}{2}xw^2 } \left| {\frac{1}{{w^p K_p (w)}} - \frac{{2^{1 - p} }}{{\Gamma (p)}}} \right|{\rm d}w}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - \frac{1}{2}t^2 } \left| {\frac{1}{{(t/\sqrt x )^p K_p (t/\sqrt x )}} - \frac{{2^{1 - p} }}{{\Gamma (p)}}} \right|{\rm d}t}. 
$$
From the asymptotic properties of the modified Bessel function,
$$
\left| {\frac{1}{{(t/\sqrt x )^p K_p (t/\sqrt x )}} - \frac{{2^{1 - p} }}{{\Gamma (p)}}} \right| \ll (1 + t)^{1/2 - p} {\rm e}^t 
$$
for all $t>0$, uniformly in $x\ge 1$, say. Consequently, by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \sqrt x \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - \frac{1}{2}xw^2 } \left| {\frac{1}{{w^p K_p (w)}} - \frac{{2^{1 - p} }}{{\Gamma (p)}}} \right|{\rm d}w}  = 0.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \sqrt x \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - \frac{1}{2}xw^2 } \frac{{{\rm d}w}}{{w^p K_p (w)}}}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \sqrt x \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - \frac{1}{2}xw^2 } \frac{{2^{1 - p} }}{{\Gamma (p)}}{\rm d}w}  = \frac{{2^{1/2 - p} \sqrt \pi  }}{{\Gamma (p)}}.
$$

Comment: Hi Gary, thank you for the reply! I believe you are correct, it's indeed not 0. 
But could you elaborate more on how you reached the fourth equation (Derived from the asym. properties of the modified Bessel)?

Comment: For $0 \le t \le \sqrt x$ the quantity is bounded by the first asymptotics. For $t \ge \sqrt x$, $$
\left| {\frac{1}{{(t/\sqrt x )^p K_p (t/\sqrt x )}}} \right| \ll (t/\sqrt x )^{1/2 - p} {\rm e}^{t/\sqrt x }  \le t^{1/2 - p} {\rm e}^t  < (1 + t)^{1/2 - p} {\rm e}^t 
$$ by the second asymptotics.

Comment: Thank you again! Still, I have one question, 
From $|\frac{1}{(..)^p K_p(..)}| \ll ..$ to $|\frac{1}{(..)^p K_p(..)} - \frac{2^{1-p}}{\Gamma(p)}| \ll ..$, is it because the second part is a constant?

Comment: First question: yes. Second question: use the theorem for the $t$-integral form.

Comment: OK, I see! Thanks!